# Finding divisors of a number

Tags: c++, c++11

I tried to make a program that finds the divisors of a number that is given by the user. My program is compiling but it isn't working properly.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std ;

int main () {
    int a,x,y,z,p ;
    int d [z] ;
    y=0 ;
    cout << "Please give me the number you want me to check for dividors" << endl ;
    cin >> a ;
    for (x=2;x<a;x++){
        if(a%x==0)
            d[y]=x ;
            y++ ;
    }
    if (y==0){
        cout << a <<" has no dividors except itself and 1 and therefore, " << a <<" is a prime" << endl ;
    }
    else 
        cout << a <<" has " << y <<" dividors except itself and 1 and this dividors are :" << endl ;
        for (p=0;p<=y;p++){
            cout << d[p] <<endl ;
        }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: `d[z]` -- ask yourself a simple question. What is the size of this array?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: You say "dividor", I say "divisor", let's call the whole thing off :-)

Comment: C++ does not support arrays of run-time size. This should not even compile.

Comment: @AnT in gcc it does, although I wouldn't expect it to handle directly uninitialized variable, better not even guess what machine code is emitted there. But I wonder how many warnings is OP ignoring (or didn't switch ON in the first place). OP: *"My program is compiling"* - this is of little importance, when you want to end with correct program fully solving your task. That requires much much more effort, and consciousness in writing the source, with lot of debugging and verifying afterwards.

Comment: BTW, that code has so many problems, even on algorithm level... it almost looks like you have even no idea what you are doing on Math level. you should probably get back to that and read more theory first, how to search for factors of number.

Answer (score 0):

I would add this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Anyway, I believe the problem is located in your last for loop. You're iterating up to `p <= y` when `y` is the number of divisors you have in the array `d[]`. `d[y]` is out-of-bounds and the loop should only iterate as long as `p < y`.